# vagrant ports report in use after reload

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I have a few vagrant VMs (both on Mac and windows, all running linux). I have port forwarding defined like this in the Vagrant file:

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 9007
```

The first time I do a `vagrant up` it works fine. But then when I do a `vagrant reload` or `vagrant halt` followed by `vagrant up` I get this message:

```
Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with some other application that is already listening
on these ports. The forwarded port to 9007 is already in use
on the host machine.

To fix this, modify your current project's Vagrantfile to use another
port. Example, where '1234' would be replaced by a unique host port:

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 1234

Sometimes, Vagrant will attempt to auto-correct this for you. In this
case, Vagrant was unable to. This is usually because the guest machine
is in a state which doesn't allow modifying port forwarding. You could
try 'vagrant reload' (equivalent of running a halt followed by an up)
so vagrant can attempt to auto-correct this upon booting. Be warned
that any unsaved work might be lost.
```

Then I have to change the port to bring up the VM, which is a pain. I have checked with netstat and lsof, and nothing seems to be using the port. I though it was perhaps a timing issue, and after a while I could use the port, but even after waiting many hours I still get the error.

This happens in both the Mac and Windows environments. Is there some setting that would allow me to reuse the ports?

Answer (score 0):

I generally use static IP to avoid issues with port forwarding. Vagrant has an `auto_correct` feature to help fix that.

from [vagrant forwarded port docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html#port-collisions-and-correction)

> It is common when running multiple Vagrant machines to unknowingly
>   create forwarded port definitions that collide with each other (two
>   separate Vagrant projects forwarded to port 8080, for example).
>   Vagrant includes built-in mechanism to detect this and correct it,
>   automatically.
>
> Port collision detection is always done. Vagrant will not allow you to
>   define a forwarded port where the port on the host appears to be
>   accepting traffic or connections.
>
> Port collision auto-correction must be manually enabled for each
>   forwarded port, since it is often surprising when it occurs and can
>   lead the Vagrant user to think that the port was not properly
>   forwarded. Enabling auto correct is easy:
>
> ```
> Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
>   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080,
>     auto_correct: true
> end
> ```
>
> The final `:auto_correct` parameter set to true tells Vagrant to auto
>   correct any collisions. During a vagrant up or vagrant reload, Vagrant
>   will output information about any collisions detections and auto
>   corrections made, so you can take notice and act accordingly.

Comment: How does using a static IP help with this? There is no actual port collision. I am only running one VM, and it's working fine. Then I do a `vagrant reload` on it, and then it says there is a port collision with the port it was just using. Seems that the port is not closed on the host, or something lime that.

Comment: static IP helps because you don't need to forward port from the VM as you access directly the server running on your VM from their IP so you can access any port from the VM without specifying the forward option.

Comment: OK, that's good to know. But I would like to figure out why I get the port collision when there is none.